# How can I find a docker swarm node status history (Down, Ready, ..)?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

my docker swarm nodes are not stable, they crash and get back to Ready in seconds
I need a command to see each node status history, when was is Down and when did it get back to Ready
the docker node inspect shows only the current status

I tried docker node inspect
I was expecting the node status history

Comment: try this https://kifarunix.com/monitor-docker-swarm-node-metrics-using-grafana/